# Looking for a free/cheap backup solution on OS X for NTFS external HDD

Tags: macos, backup, external-disk

I'm looking for an incremental backup system on OS X that plays nice with USB NTFS-formatted external HDDs. I am currently using [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com) to work with the HDD, but since Time Machine doesn't work with NTFS drives, I have just been manually copying files from my HDD to back it up (ugh).

I need to use an NTFS drive because I am going back and forth between Windows machines at my school and a Mac at home. I have no permissions at my school to install any Windows software, so I am forced to find an OS X solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Time Machine. [This page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382) tells how to enable NTFS for writing from Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

CrashPlan is great for Mac backup. But it dose NOT officially support NTFS Drives. There is a workaround. and I have made it work.  See here:

http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/recipe/back_up_windows_mapped_drives

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience using the Mac client at all.  So I can't say for sure whether it specifically works with an NTFS formatted drive.  But [CrashPlan](http://crashplan.com) has a client that can theoretically do what you want for free.